# How to switch back from Chrome OS to Ubuntu 12.04 on Acer C7 chromebook?

Tags: acer, chromeos

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my Acer C7 chromebook. Once I installed it, I never switched back to Chrome OS. But yesterday when I got back home, I found that my laptop LED was on, and the Chrome OS was running. How can I go back to my Ubuntu 12.04? I usually had a screen that has a chrome logo on it every time I turn on my laptop, where I always pressed Ctrl+D to run Ubuntu, but this screen no longer appears when I boot.

Comment: Thank you again Marc for your answer and help; I highly appreciate it. I remember getting Ubuntu following these steps: [Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on Acer C7 Chromebook \[Complete Guide.\]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qpjTzav3kw) You can get more detailed information by clicking "more" below the video section; you might see some websites where some articles that you are familiar with. My brother, who put me in this situation, on the start page where you get to whether wait for 30 second or press "ctrl+D" to proceed to your default operating system, he followed the steps on the screen to re-

Comment: pls i have a problem, i didnt partition by loginning as chronos first. i went str8 to the chrome browser n just typed in shell and installed the ubuntu package with crouton. now the command for makin ubuntu the default os doesnt work, and its a job i was given. the owner of the laptop needs it before evening.pls help, any possible suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [True Ubuntu on Chromebook ARM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm)

Comment: Doesn't look like a dupe to me

Answer (score 3):

The solution was ever easier than I could imagine. The first thing one should do is to enter developer mode, then log in as "Chronos" and enter:

```
sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 dev/sda
exit
```

... and reboot. This should make Ubuntu your default system. Special thanks to you mr Marc for your help!

Comment: I highly recommend, if you haven't already, reading my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/930272/690724) and following it so your computer runs faster and more smoothly. Also, if you don't mind, give it an upvote so I can try to surpass the answers above as they are deprecated and dangerous for other users to follow on newer Chromebooks.