# How to get back to Ubuntu from Chrome OS?

Tags: chromebook

I installed Ubuntu from lifehacker.com, onto my Acer Chromebook, where you access it by switching back and forth between Chrome OS and Ubuntu with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>. I shut down my computer and when I turned it on, I was unable to access Ubuntu again.

I need help getting back to it to install some programs that I require.

Comment: hope this help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/303341/how-to-switch-back-from-chrome-os-to-ubuntu-12-04-on-acer-c7-chromebook

Answer (score 0):

If you can still get to chrome OS, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up crouton. Type `shell` then `sudo startxfce4`.

It should then start your Ubuntu OS.